# Regex for at least one instance of each of a list of letters?

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, stringr

I'm trying to sharpen my skills with regular expressions by coming up with some R code to solve the NY Time's Spelling Bee game.

I've done that, but now I'm going one step further and trying to identify specifically what the game calls "pangrams"--words that contain at least one instance of each of set of seven letters.

I was hoping to do this with `str_detect()` and a `regex`, but I'm not seeing a way to say "at least one of each of these letters."

Per the second example [here](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_detect.html), the function can be used over a list of letters, but I'm running into problems when the string I want to compare against is in a tibble with a list of words.

This does not work (to identify `"pedagogy"` as the pangram):

```
library(tidyverse)

required_letters <- c("o", "a", "d", "e", "g", "p", "y")
list_of_words <- tibble(word = c("pedagogy", "agog", "apogee", "dodge"))

pangrams <- list_of_words %>%
  filter(all(str_detect(word, required_letters)))
```

But I was hoping it would work in the way that this does:

```
all(str_detect("pedagogy", required_letters))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regex, you can create a pattern using look ahead for each letter:

```
pattern <- str_c("(?=.*", required_letters, ")", collapse = "") 

list_of_words %>%
   filter(str_detect(word, pattern))

# A tibble: 1 × 1
  word    
  <chr>   
1 pedagogy
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do `str_detect` rowwise:

```r
list_of_words %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(all(str_detect(word, required_letters))) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 1 × 1
#   word    
#   <chr>
# 1 pedagogy
```

or use `map_lgl` from `purrr`:

```r
list_of_words %>%
  filter(map_lgl(word, ~ all(str_detect(.x, required_letters))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a combination of `rowSums` and `sapply` using `str_detect`:

```
library(stringr)
list_of_words |>
  filter(rowSums(sapply(required_letters, str_detect, string = word)) == length(required_letters))
```

```
 word    
  <chr>   
1 pedagogy
```

Comment: This would fsil. Eg if the word was `aaaaaaaa` it would pass it as true